# Comparar dos ramas sin tener en cuenta las líneas en blanco y tabs - Git

Tags: git, comparaciones

Tengo dos ramas en GIT con objetos que he extraído de dos bases de datos (paquetes de Oracle), y necesito compararlos para ver si hay diferencias en el código, sin tener en cuenta los espacios en blanco y los tabs que han quedado dentro del código. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto con Git diff?

Answer (score 4):

Si lo que se desea es comparar las dos ramas, **ignorando los espacios en blanco**, la comparación sería algo como:

```
git diff master..alter -w --ignore-all-space
```

Donde `alter` es la rama que contiene las modificiones con los espacios en blanco.
Al ejecutar este comando, me arroja (*simplificado*):

```
+THIS IS NEW
\ No newline at end of file
```

Que no está trayendo las lineas a las que le agregué espacios en blanco.

**Nota**: Como comprobación, ejecuté:

```
git diff master..alter
```

En la prueba que hice me da el siguiente resultado (*simplificado*):

```
-## License
-The Unlicense (i.e Public Domain)
-
+## License 
+The Unlicense (i.e Public Domain) 
+ 
+THIS IS NEW
\ No newline at end of file
```

Que si trae las lineas con espacios en blanco.

Espero sea lo que estás necesitando.